# Floating-Point Variables and Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception, floating-point

My program is supposed to accept a floating-point variable and then exit. However I am practicing some exception handling stuff and found a problem. Whenever you enter a letter into this program the program of course throws an InputMismatchException but it gets stuck inside an infinite loop. I assume my problem is based off of my misunderstanding of try-catch statements and exception handling.

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean done = false;

    do{
        try{
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            float number = reader.nextFloat();
            done = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("uh oh");
        }
    }while(!done);
}
```

This problem does not occur if I use a different variable type so I'm not sure if it's a logical error or just something funky with floating-point variables.

Comment: What do you mean "infinite loop"? Do you get any output?

Comment: Yes I get the statement "Enter a number: uh oh" over and over again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Float#nextFloat()` does not consume the token in the `Scanner` if it throws an `InputMismatchException`. So when you get the exception and loop (because `done` is still `false`), you try to call `nextFloat()` again. Since the token is still not a value that can parsed into a `float`, the `Scanner` again throws the exception. And again, and again, ad nauseam.

You should use `hasNextFloat()` to check for the existence of a token that can be parsed to a `float` value. Or consume the incorrect value with `Scanner#next()`, as suggested by [Quirliom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387903/floating-point-variables-and-exception-handling/28387954#comment45113418_28387954).

Comment: It's worth noting that if `hasNextFloat()` returns false, the input stream should be moved on with `next()`...